# Apply boostrap bootstrap.min.css file to only one div or control like datetimepicker? How to

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a big project that is already fully developed now i just want to change the datetime control for that i am using these files and datetimepicker loads correctly but effects my CSS of all control and page here is files

```
<link href="../CSS/bootstrap/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="../JS/bootstrap/moment-with-locales.js"></script>
<script src="../JS/bootstrap/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"></script>
```

now **bootstrap.min.css**  provide style to datetimepicker and effects all page here is my div for datetimepicker

```
          <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                            <tr>
                                <td width="250px">
                                    <div class="row">
                            <div class="col_4">
               <%-- <style scoped>
    @import "../CSS/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css";
   </style>  --%>
            <input type="text"    id="EnrolDatepicker" />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                  </tr>
        </table>
```

Solution 1: I tried scope as in code but it do same not working

Solution 2: i figure out related css for datetime picker but it too effect the td and table and also not proper style applied to datetimepicker

**Now**
Can anybody tell me how to apply this boostrap.min.css to just one control or div

**UPDATE**

Following karithk answer link to libraries work for GUI handling of datetimepicker

```
  <link href="../CSS/bootstrap/bootstrap-datetimepicker-standalone.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<link href="../CSS/bootstrap/bootstrap-datetimepicker-standalone.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

but its position is not on text box input upon which i am applying this datetimepicker

**Now** How to handle it position exact on input feild
[Image to issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VggKm.png)

I figured out class

```
      .bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget.dropdown-menu.usetwentyfour
```

Comment: Try to separate the control on different page and load that page wherever you want to use the  datetimepicker control. you can also try to list out css used for datetimepicker control and add same instead of adding entire css file.

Comment: Bootstrap is meant to affect the entire page and make it mobile as a priority. This changes the default styling quite a lot. You can't just have bootstrap affect only one part of the page. You would be better off getting a full copy of bootstrap and copying out the few classes you are using that affect the datepicker. That, or use a different datepicker like that wouldn't affect everything on the page.

Comment: just include these https://cdnjs.com/libraries/bootstrap-datetimepicker

Comment: This work for design i adjust libraries I am adding in edit portion but datetimepicker appears on top of page it have to be appear only below control its postion issue

Comment: SEE UPDATE PLEASE @KarthikGanesan

Comment: SEE IMAGE I ADDED TO ISSUE @KarthikGanesan

Comment: @KarthikGanesan you are right thanks

Answer (score 4):

I suggests you create a [custom bootstrap file](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/) by selecting only *Forms* under *Common CSS* section, and then run a [prefixer](http://www.css-prefix.com/) over it, adding a prefix, e.g. `#bootstrap-container`. Then you add only what you want to be managed by boostrap in an specific element, like `div#bootstrap-container`:

```css
#bootstrap-container html{font-family:sans-serif;-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%}
#bootstrap-container body{margin:0}
#bootstrap-container article, #bootstrap-container aside, #bootstrap-container details, #bootstrap-container figcaption, #bootstrap-container figure, #bootstrap-container footer, #bootstrap-container header, #bootstrap-container hgroup, #bootstrap-container main, #bootstrap-container menu, #bootstrap-container nav, #bootstrap-container section, #bootstrap-container summary{display:block}
#bootstrap-container audio, #bootstrap-container canvas, #bootstrap-container progress, #bootstrap-container video{display:inline-block;vertical-align:baseline}
#bootstrap-container audio:not([controls]){display:none;height:0}
#bootstrap-container [hidden], #bootstrap-container template{display:none}
#bootstrap-container a{background-color:transparent}
#bootstrap-container a:active, #bootstrap-container a:hover{outline:0}
#bootstrap-container abbr[title]{border-bottom:1px dotted}
#bootstrap-container b, #bootstrap-container strong{font-weight:bold}
#bootstrap-container dfn{font-style:italic}
#bootstrap-container h1{font-size:2em;margin:0.67em 0}
#bootstrap-container mark{background:#ff0;color:#000}
#bootstrap-container small{font-size:80%}
#bootstrap-container sub, #bootstrap-container sup{font-size:75%;line-height:0;position:relative;vertical-align:baseline}
#bootstrap-container sup{top:-0.5em}
#bootstrap-container sub{bottom:-0.25em}
#bootstrap-container img{border:0}
#bootstrap-container svg:not(:root){overflow:hidden}
#bootstrap-container figure{margin:1em 40px}
#bootstrap-container hr{-webkit-box-sizing:content-box;-moz-box-sizing:content-box;box-sizing:content-box;height:0}
#bootstrap-container pre{overflow:auto}
#bootstrap-container code, #bootstrap-container kbd, #bootstrap-container pre, #bootstrap-container samp{font-family:monospace, #bootstrap-container  monospace;font-size:1em}
#bootstrap-container button, #bootstrap-container input, #bootstrap-container optgroup, #bootstrap-container select, #bootstrap-container textarea{color:inherit;font:inherit;margin:0}
#bootstrap-container button{overflow:visible}
#bootstrap-container button, #bootstrap-container select{text-transform:none}
#bootstrap-container button, #bootstrap-container html input[type="button"], #bootstrap-container input[type="reset"], #bootstrap-container input[type="submit"]{-webkit-appearance:button;cursor:pointer}
#bootstrap-container button[disabled], #bootstrap-container html input[disabled]{cursor:default}
#bootstrap-container button::-moz-focus-inner, #bootstrap-container input::-moz-focus-inner{border:0;padding:0}
#bootstrap-container input{line-height:normal}
#bootstrap-container input[type="checkbox"], #bootstrap-container input[type="radio"]{-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;-moz-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box;padding:0}
#bootstrap-container input[type="number"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button, #bootstrap-container input[type="number"]::-webkit-outer-spin-button{height:auto}
#bootstrap-container input[type="search"]{-webkit-appearance:textfield;-webkit-box-sizing:content-box;-moz-box-sizing:content-box;box-sizing:content-box}
#bootstrap-container input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button, #bootstrap-container input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-decoration{-webkit-appearance:none}
#bootstrap-container fieldset{border:1px solid #c0c0c0;margin:0 2px;padding:0.35em 0.625em 0.75em}
#bootstrap-container legend{border:0;padding:0}
#bootstrap-container textarea{overflow:auto}
#bootstrap-container optgroup{font-weight:bold}
#bootstrap-container table{border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0}
#bootstrap-container td, #bootstrap-container th{padding:0}
#bootstrap-container *{-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;-moz-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box}
#bootstrap-container *:before, #bootstrap-container *:after{-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;-moz-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box}
#bootstrap-container html{font-size:10px;-webkit-tap-highlight-color:rgba(0, #bootstrap-container 0, #bootstrap-container 0, #bootstrap-container 0)}
#bootstrap-container body{font-family:"Helvetica Neue", #bootstrap-container Helvetica, #bootstrap-container Arial, #bootstrap-container sans-serif;font-size:14px;line-height:1.42857143;color:#333;background-color:#fff}
#bootstrap-container input, #bootstrap-container button, #bootstrap-container select, #bootstrap-container textarea{font-family:inherit;font-size:inherit;line-height:inherit}
#bootstrap-container a{color:#337ab7;text-decoration:none}
#bootstrap-container a:hover, #bootstrap-container a:focus{color:#23527c;text-decoration:underline}
#bootstrap-container a:focus{outline:5px auto -webkit-focus-ring-color;outline-offset:-2px}
#bootstrap-container figure{margin:0}
#bootstrap-container img{vertical-align:middle}
#bootstrap-container .img-responsive{display:block;max-width:100%;height:auto}
#bootstrap-container .img-rounded{border-radius:6px}
#bootstrap-container .img-thumbnail{padding:4px;line-height:1.42857143;background-color:#fff;border:1px solid #ddd;border-radius:4px;-webkit-transition:all .2s ease-in-out;-o-transition:all .2s ease-in-out;transition:all .2s ease-in-out;display:inline-block;max-width:100%;height:auto}
#bootstrap-container .img-circle{border-radius:50%}
#bootstrap-container hr{margin-top:20px;margin-bottom:20px;border:0;border-top:1px solid #eee}
#bootstrap-container .sr-only{position:absolute;width:1px;height:1px;margin:-1px;padding:0;overflow:hidden;clip:rect(0, #bootstrap-container  0, #bootstrap-container  0, #bootstrap-container  0);border:0}
#bootstrap-container .sr-only-focusable:active, #bootstrap-container .sr-only-focusable:focus{position:static;width:auto;height:auto;margin:0;overflow:visible;clip:auto}
#bootstrap-container [role="button"]{cursor:pointer}
#bootstrap-container fieldset{padding:0;margin:0;border:0;min-width:0}
#bootstrap-container legend{display:block;width:100%;padding:0;margin-bottom:20px;font-size:21px;line-height:inherit;color:#333;border:0;border-bottom:1px solid #e5e5e5}
#bootstrap-container label{display:inline-block;max-width:100%;margin-bottom:5px;font-weight:bold}
#bootstrap-container input[type="search"]{-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;-moz-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box}
#bootstrap-container input[type="radio"], #bootstrap-container input[type="checkbox"]{margin:4px 0 0;margin-top:1px \9;line-height:normal}
#bootstrap-container input[type="file"]{display:block}
#bootstrap-container input[type="range"]{display:block;width:100%}
#bootstrap-container select[multiple], #bootstrap-container select[size]{height:auto}
#bootstrap-container input[type="file"]:focus, #bootstrap-container input[type="radio"]:focus, #bootstrap-container input[type="checkbox"]:focus{outline:5px auto -webkit-focus-ring-color;outline-offset:-2px}
#bootstrap-container output{display:block;padding-top:7px;font-size:14px;line-height:1.42857143;color:#555}
#bootstrap-container .form-control{display:block;width:100%;height:34px;padding:6px 12px;font-size:14px;line-height:1.42857143;color:#555;background-color:#fff;background-image:none;border:1px solid #ccc;border-radius:4px;-webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, #bootstrap-container 0, #bootstrap-container 0, #bootstrap-container 0.075);box-shadow:inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, #bootstrap-container 0, #bootstrap-container 0, #bootstrap-container 0.075);-webkit-transition:border-color ease-in-out .15s, #bootstrap-container  -webkit-box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;-o-transition:border-color ease-in-out .15s, #bootstrap-container  box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;transition:border-color ease-in-out .15s, #bootstrap-container  box-shadow ease-in-out .15s}
#bootstrap-container .form-control:focus{border-color:#66afe9;outline:0;-webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, #bootstrap-container 0, #bootstrap-container 0, #bootstrap-container .075), #bootstrap-container  0 0 8px rgba(102, #bootstrap-container  175, #bootstrap-container  233, #bootstrap-container  0.6);box-shadow:inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, #bootstrap-container 0, #bootstrap-container 0, #bootstrap-container .075), #bootstrap-container  0 0 8px rgba(102, #bootstrap-container  175, #bootstrap-container  233, #bootstrap-container  0.6)}
#bootstrap-container .form-control::-moz-placeholder{color:#999;opacity:1}
#bootstrap-container .form-control:-ms-input-placeholder{color:#999}
#bootstrap-container .form-control::-webkit-input-placeholder{color:#999}
#bootstrap-container .form-control::-ms-expand{border:0;background-color:transparent}
#bootstrap-container .form-control[disabled], #bootstrap-container .form-control[readonly], #bootstrap-container fieldset[disabled] .form-control{background-color:#eee;opacity:1}
#bootstrap-container .form-control[disabled], #bootstrap-container fieldset[disabled] .form-control{cursor:not-allowed}
#bootstrap-container textarea.form-control{height:auto}
#bootstrap-container input[type="search"]{-webkit-appearance:none}
#bootstrap-container @media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0){input[type="date"].form-control, #bootstrap-container input[type="time"].form-control, #bootstrap-container input[type="datetime-local"].form-control, #bootstrap-container input[type="month"].form-control{line-height:34px}
#bootstrap-container input[type="date"].input-sm, #bootstrap-container input[type="time"].input-sm, #bootstrap-container input[type="datetime-local"].input-sm, #bootstrap-container input[type="month"].input-sm, #bootstrap-container .input-group-sm input[type="date"], #bootstrap-container .input-group-sm input[type="time"], #bootstrap-container .input-group-sm input[type="datetime-local"], #bootstrap-container .input-group-sm input[type="month"]{line-height:30px}
#bootstrap-container input[type="date"].input-lg, #bootstrap-container input[type="time"].input-lg, #bootstrap-container input[type="datetime-local"].input-lg, #bootstrap-container input[type="month"].input-lg, #bootstrap-container .input-group-lg input[type="date"], #bootstrap-container .input-group-lg input[type="time"], #bootstrap-container .input-group-lg input[type="datetime-local"], #bootstrap-container .input-group-lg input[type="month"]{line-height:46px}
}
#bootstrap-container .form-group{margin-bottom:15px}
#bootstrap-container .radio, #bootstrap-container .checkbox{position:relative;display:block;margin-top:10px;margin-bottom:10px}
#bootstrap-container .radio label, #bootstrap-container .checkbox label{min-height:20px;padding-left:20px;margin-bottom:0;font-weight:normal;cursor:pointer}
#bootstrap-container .radio input[type="radio"], #bootstrap-container .radio-inline input[type="radio"], #bootstrap-container .checkbox input[type="checkbox"], #bootstrap-container .checkbox-inline input[type="checkbox"]{position:absolute;margin-left:-20px;margin-top:4px \9}
#bootstrap-container .radio+.radio, #bootstrap-container .checkbox+.checkbox{margin-top:-5px}
#bootstrap-container .radio-inline, #bootstrap-container .checkbox-inline{position:relative;display:inline-block;padding-left:20px;margin-bottom:0;vertical-align:middle;font-weight:normal;cursor:pointer}
#bootstrap-container .radio-inline+.radio-inline, #bootstrap-container .checkbox-inline+.checkbox-inline{margin-top:0;margin-left:10px}
#bootstrap-container input[type="radio"][disabled], #bootstrap-container input[type="checkbox"][disabled], #bootstrap-container input[type="radio"].disabled, #bootstrap-container input[type="checkbox"].disabled, #bootstrap-container fieldset[disabled] input[type="radio"], #bootstrap-container fieldset[disabled] input[type="checkbox"]{cursor:not-allowed}
#bootstrap-container .radio-inline.disabled, #bootstrap-container .checkbox-inline.disabled, #bootstrap-container fieldset[disabled] .radio-inline, #bootstrap-container fieldset[disabled] .checkbox-inline{cursor:not-allowed}
#bootstrap-container .radio.disabled label, #bootstrap-container .checkbox.disabled label, #bootstrap-container fieldset[disabled] .radio label, #bootstrap-container fieldset[disabled] .checkbox label{cursor:not-allowed}
#bootstrap-container .form-control-static{padding-top:7px;padding-bottom:7px;margin-bottom:0;min-height:34px}
#bootstrap-container .form-control-static.input-lg, #bootstrap-container .form-control-static.input-sm{padding-left:0;padding-right:0}
#bootstrap-container .input-sm{height:30px;padding:5px 10px;font-size:12px;line-height:1.5;border-radius:3px}
#bootstrap-container select.input-sm{height:30px;line-height:30px}
#bootstrap-container textarea.input-sm, #bootstrap-container select[multiple].input-sm{height:auto}
#bootstrap-container .form-group-sm .form-control{height:30px;padding:5px 10px;font-size:12px;line-height:1.5;border-radius:3px}
#bootstrap-container .form-group-sm select.form-control{height:30px;line-height:30px}
#bootstrap-container .form-group-sm textarea.form-control, #bootstrap-container .form-group-sm select[multiple].form-control{height:auto}
#bootstrap-container .form-group-sm .form-control-static{height:30px;min-height:32px;padding:6px 10px;font-size:12px;line-height:1.5}
#bootstrap-container .input-lg{height:46px;padding:10px 16px;font-size:18px;line-height:1.3333333;border-radius:6px}
#bootstrap-container select.input-lg{height:46px;line-height:46px}
#bootstrap-container textarea.input-lg, #bootstrap-container select[multiple].input-lg{height:auto}
#bootstrap-container .form-group-lg .form-control{height:46px;padding:10px 16px;font-size:18px;line-height:1.3333333;border-radius:6px}
#bootstrap-container .form-group-lg select.form-control{height:46px;line-height:46px}
#bootstrap-container .form-group-lg textarea.form-control, #bootstrap-container .form-group-lg select[multiple].form-control{height:auto}
#bootstrap-container .form-group-lg .form-control-static{height:46px;min-height:38px;padding:11px 16px;font-size:18px;line-height:1.3333333}
#bootstrap-container .has-feedback{position:relative}
#bootstrap-container .has-feedback .form-control{padding-right:42.5px}
#bootstrap-container .form-control-feedback{position:absolute;top:0;right:0;z-index:2;display:block;width:34px;height:34px;line-height:34px;text-align:center;pointer-events:none}
#bootstrap-container .input-lg+.form-control-feedback, #bootstrap-container .input-group-lg+.form-control-feedback, #bootstrap-container .form-group-lg .form-control+.form-control-feedback{width:46px;height:46px;line-height:46px}
#bootstrap-container .input-sm+.form-control-feedback, #bootstrap-container .input-group-sm+.form-control-feedback, #bootstrap-container .form-group-sm .form-control+.form-control-feedback{width:30px;height:30px;line-height:30px}
#bootstrap-container .has-success .help-block, #bootstrap-container .has-success .control-label, #bootstrap-container .has-success .radio, #bootstrap-container .has-success .checkbox, #bootstrap-container .has-success .radio-inline, #bootstrap-container .has-success .checkbox-inline, #bootstrap-container .has-success.radio label, #bootstrap-container .has-success.checkbox label, #bootstrap-container .has-success.radio-inline label, #bootstrap-container .has-success.checkbox-inline label{color:#3c763d}
#bootstrap-container .has-success .form-control{border-color:#3c763d;-webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, #bootstrap-container 0, #bootstrap-container 0, #bootstrap-container 0.075);box-shadow:inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, #bootstrap-container 0, #bootstrap-container 0, #bootstrap-container 0.075)}
#bootstrap-container .has-success .form-control:focus{border-color:#2b542c;-webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, #bootstrap-container 0, #bootstrap-container 0, #bootstrap-container 0.075), #bootstrap-container 0 0 6px #67b168;box-shadow:inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, #bootstrap-container 0, #bootstrap-container 0, #bootstrap-container 0.075), #bootstrap-container 0 0 6px #67b168}
#bootstrap-container .has-success .input-group-addon{color:#3c763d;border-color:#3c763d;background-color:#dff0d8}
#bootstrap-container .has-success .form-control-feedback{color:#3c763d}
#bootstrap-container .has-warning .help-block, #bootstrap-container .has-warning .control-label, #bootstrap-container .has-warning .radio, #bootstrap-container .has-warning .checkbox, #bootstrap-container .has-warning .radio-inline, #bootstrap-container .has-warning .checkbox-inline, #bootstrap-container .has-warning.radio label, #bootstrap-container .has-warning.checkbox label, #bootstrap-container .has-warning.radio-inline label, #bootstrap-container .has-warning.checkbox-inline label{color:#8a6d3b}
#bootstrap-container .has-warning .form-control{border-color:#8a6d3b;-webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, #bootstrap-container 0, #bootstrap-container 0, #bootstrap-container 0.075);box-shadow:inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, #bootstrap-container 0, #bootstrap-container 0, #bootstrap-container 0.075)}
#bootstrap-container .has-warning .form-control:focus{border-color:#66512c;-webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, #bootstrap-container 0, #bootstrap-container 0, #bootstrap-container 0.075), #bootstrap-container 0 0 6px #c0a16b;box-shadow:inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, #bootstrap-container 0, #bootstrap-container 0, #bootstrap-container 0.075), #bootstrap-container 0 0 6px #c0a16b}
#bootstrap-container .has-warning .input-group-addon{color:#8a6d3b;border-color:#8a6d3b;background-color:#fcf8e3}
#bootstrap-container .has-warning .form-control-feedback{color:#8a6d3b}
#bootstrap-container .has-error .help-block, #bootstrap-container .has-error .control-label, #bootstrap-container .has-error .radio, #bootstrap-container .has-error .checkbox, #bootstrap-container .has-error .radio-inline, #bootstrap-container .has-error .checkbox-inline, #bootstrap-container .has-error.radio label, #bootstrap-container .has-error.checkbox label, #bootstrap-container .has-error.radio-inline label, #bootstrap-container .has-error.checkbox-inline label{color:#a94442}
#bootstrap-container .has-error .form-control{border-color:#a94442;-webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, #bootstrap-container 0, #bootstrap-container 0, #bootstrap-container 0.075);box-shadow:inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, #bootstrap-container 0, #bootstrap-container 0, #bootstrap-container 0.075)}
#bootstrap-container .has-error .form-control:focus{border-color:#843534;-webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, #bootstrap-container 0, #bootstrap-container 0, #bootstrap-container 0.075), #bootstrap-container 0 0 6px #ce8483;box-shadow:inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, #bootstrap-container 0, #bootstrap-container 0, #bootstrap-container 0.075), #bootstrap-container 0 0 6px #ce8483}
#bootstrap-container .has-error .input-group-addon{color:#a94442;border-color:#a94442;background-color:#f2dede}
#bootstrap-container .has-error .form-control-feedback{color:#a94442}
#bootstrap-container .has-feedback label~.form-control-feedback{top:25px}
#bootstrap-container .has-feedback label.sr-only~.form-control-feedback{top:0}
#bootstrap-container .help-block{display:block;margin-top:5px;margin-bottom:10px;color:#737373}
#bootstrap-container @media (min-width:768px){.form-inline .form-group{display:inline-block;margin-bottom:0;vertical-align:middle}
#bootstrap-container .form-inline .form-control{display:inline-block;width:auto;vertical-align:middle}
#bootstrap-container .form-inline .form-control-static{display:inline-block}
#bootstrap-container .form-inline .input-group{display:inline-table;vertical-align:middle}
#bootstrap-container .form-inline .input-group .input-group-addon, #bootstrap-container .form-inline .input-group .input-group-btn, #bootstrap-container .form-inline .input-group .form-control{width:auto}
#bootstrap-container .form-inline .input-group>.form-control{width:100%}
#bootstrap-container .form-inline .control-label{margin-bottom:0;vertical-align:middle}
#bootstrap-container .form-inline .radio, #bootstrap-container .form-inline .checkbox{display:inline-block;margin-top:0;margin-bottom:0;vertical-align:middle}
#bootstrap-container .form-inline .radio label, #bootstrap-container .form-inline .checkbox label{padding-left:0}
#bootstrap-container .form-inline .radio input[type="radio"], #bootstrap-container .form-inline .checkbox input[type="checkbox"]{position:relative;margin-left:0}
#bootstrap-container .form-inline .has-feedback .form-control-feedback{top:0}
}
#bootstrap-container .form-horizontal .radio, #bootstrap-container .form-horizontal .checkbox, #bootstrap-container .form-horizontal .radio-inline, #bootstrap-container .form-horizontal .checkbox-inline{margin-top:0;margin-bottom:0;padding-top:7px}
#bootstrap-container .form-horizontal .radio, #bootstrap-container .form-horizontal .checkbox{min-height:27px}
#bootstrap-container .form-horizontal .form-group{margin-left:-15px;margin-right:-15px}
#bootstrap-container @media (min-width:768px){.form-horizontal .control-label{text-align:right;margin-bottom:0;padding-top:7px}
}
#bootstrap-container .form-horizontal .has-feedback .form-control-feedback{right:15px}
#bootstrap-container @media (min-width:768px){.form-horizontal .form-group-lg .control-label{padding-top:11px;font-size:18px}
}
#bootstrap-container @media (min-width:768px){.form-horizontal .form-group-sm .control-label{padding-top:6px;font-size:12px}
}
#bootstrap-container .clearfix:before, #bootstrap-container .clearfix:after, #bootstrap-container .form-horizontal .form-group:before, #bootstrap-container .form-horizontal .form-group:after{content:" ";display:table}
#bootstrap-container .clearfix:after, #bootstrap-container .form-horizontal .form-group:after{clear:both}
#bootstrap-container .center-block{display:block;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto}
#bootstrap-container .pull-right{float:right !important}
#bootstrap-container .pull-left{float:left !important}
#bootstrap-container .hide{display:none !important}
#bootstrap-container .show{display:block !important}
#bootstrap-container .invisible{visibility:hidden}
#bootstrap-container .text-hide{font:0/0 a;color:transparent;text-shadow:none;background-color:transparent;border:0}
#bootstrap-container .hidden{display:none !important}
#bootstrap-container .affix{position:fixed}
```

```html
<form class="form">
  <input class="form-control" />
</form>
<div id="bootstrap-container">
  <form class="form">
    <input class="form-control" />
  </form>
</div>
```

Note in the above code that even an element using a bootstrap class would not receive it's classes outside the container.

Comment: SEE UPDATED NOTE AND IMAGE

Answer (score 0):

Use some script for this perpose. In current situation, you are using a complete framework only for one eliment.